# Don't Insert record in `SQLite` table while syntax is correct

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I have a table called `TABLE_MSG`.I can't insert into it the records. `insert` function returns `-1` value. I put several `log` in `insert` function and show me my model correctly passed to `insert` function and `ContentValues` has value and isn't null.It seems every things is correct but `insert` doesn't work.
Here is my model.

```
public class message_model implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("thread_id")
private int thread_id;
@SerializedName("user_id")
private int user_id;
@SerializedName("body")
private String body;
@SerializedName("created_at")
private String created_at;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
private String updated_at;
@SerializedName("deleted_at")
private String deleted_at;
// also I write getter and setter
}
```

This is query of create table.

```
String CREATE_TABLE_MSG = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MSG + " ("
            + MSG_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + MSG_T_ID + " INTEGER," + MSG_U_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + MSG_BODY + " TEXT," + MSG_C_AT + " TEXT," + MSG_U_AT + " TEXT," + MSG_D_AT + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MSG);
```

This is `add_message` function.

```
 public void add_message(message_model model) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MSG_ID,model.getId());
        values.put(MSG_T_ID, model.getThread_id());
        values.put(MSG_U_ID, model.getUser_id());
        values.put(MSG_BODY, model.getBody());
        values.put(MSG_C_AT, model.getCreated_at());
        values.put(MSG_U_AT, model.getUpdated_at());
        values.put(MSG_D_AT, model.getDeleted_at());
        Log.e("MESSAGE",values.toString()+" toString value \n");
        Log.e("MESSAGE",model.toString());
        long rowInserted= db.insert(TABLE_MSG, null, values);
        if(rowInserted != -1)
            Log.e("MESSAGE","IN INSERT MESSAGE TABLE and log is -1");
        else
            Log.e("MESSAGE","IN INSERT MESSAGE TABLE "+rowInserted);

        db.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("MESSAGE",e.toString());
    }
}
```

This is my calling `add_message` function.

```
message_model m=new message_model(589, 300, 400, "body", "createdat", "updatedat", null);
    db.add_message(m);
```

This is `get_message` funtion.

```
public ArrayList<message_model> get_messages() {
    ArrayList<message_model> list = new ArrayList<message_model>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MSG;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            message_model model = new message_model();
            model.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            model.setThread_id(cursor.getInt(1));
            model.setUser_id(cursor.getInt(2));
            model.setBody(cursor.getString(3));
            model.setCreated_at(cursor.getString(4));
            model.setUpdated_at(cursor.getString(5));
            model.setDeleted_at(cursor.getString(6));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    Log.e("MESSAGE","in get message");
    Log.e("MESSAGE","in get message"+list.toString());
    return list;
}
```

This is my calling `get_message`.

```
 ArrayList<message_model> listm = new ArrayList<>();
   listm = db.get_messages();
  for (int i = 0; i < listm.size(); i++) {
      Log.e("MESSAGE", "body in for " + listm.get(i).getBody());
       Log.e("MESSAGE", "id in for " + listm.get(i).getId() + "");
 }
```

Comment: try commenting out `values.put(MSG_ID,model.getId());`, you using an existing id when the **id** has to be unqiue. Not specifying it will result in  the id being generated as the column is an alias of the rowid (i.e. the column is defined with  `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`).

Comment: When I get message from the table it returns an empty list.Nothing don't insert in my table so there isn't Duplicate id.

Comment: Then temporarily change to use the  `insertOrThrow` method instead of the `insert` Method. The stack-trace will then show the underlying issue.

Comment: are you getting this: `Log.e("MESSAGE","IN INSERT MESSAGE TABLE and log is -1");`

Comment: @UmangBurman Yes. I received it.

Comment: I think you are actually inserting the data, See the condition: `if(rowInserted != -1)` So if it is **NOT** equal to -1 then you are getting this.

Comment: @MikeT, My function don't enter in catch body and anything don't print in logcat.

Comment: Yep becuase you have != -1 rather than == 1 to trigger the if. So it's actually inserting you are just reporting it wrongly.

Comment: @UmangBurman. Yes you are right. I made a mistake. In fact, this is done, but why does the empty list get in the `get-message` function? I edit my question.

Comment: Can you show the code for getting the data. Also the code for assigning the list please.?

Comment: Check out my answer once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Just add this line:

```
list.add(model);
```

as shown below(Write Here):

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        message_model model = new message_model();
        model.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        model.setThread_id(cursor.getInt(1));
        model.setUser_id(cursor.getInt(2));
        model.setBody(cursor.getString(3));
        model.setCreated_at(cursor.getString(4));
        model.setUpdated_at(cursor.getString(5));
        model.setDeleted_at(cursor.getString(6));

        ......(Write Here)
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

That's it, You are just getting the data from DB but not adding it to the list

Hope it helps.